# DNS Weird Issue I've Never Seen

Tags: networking, domain-name-system

The issue i'm experiencing is that with one DNS server out of the 3 I have, any bogus dns entry always resolves to a certain IP not part of my network.

For example, nslookup abc123 = 192.124.249.12, nslookup sdfs3242 = 192.124.249.12. Even DNS entries that are valid in my network still resolve to that same IP.

If I log into the DNS server and do local queries, everything turns out fine and bogus dns entries get the expected host not found. This doesn't happen from all computers only some.

Has anyone ever experienced something like this?

Comment: Check whether that server uses localhost for its own resolution (likely not). Then check for configured upstream servers, delegations and wildcard entries.

Comment: Which software do you use? How is it configured? Had you checked logs (that correspond to making queires), what's there? How DNS is set up on computers (default domain, at least)?

Comment: For it's own resolution it's using my primary and secondary DC. No wildcard entries. What i did notice is that on my machine if i use the said DNS server that is causing issues my domain name get's appended to every entry i put in there and the value it returns it's the www value that's assigned. If I remove that DNS server and just put my primary and secondary DC then everything returns back to normal. This is the behavior I've noticed. This does not happen on another machine i tested which is the odd thing that i find. Some machines do it and some dont.

Comment: The DNS server is a windows DNS server. It's configured as an extra DNS server. All computers are inside the domain.

Comment: Nothing weird per se, you are not showing full DNS traces to debug. You probably have a search list, so all names are attempted in a given local zone, which has a wildcard.

Comment: There are no wildcards in the records. Everything is replicated from my primary DC to my secondary and then to the affected one in Azure. Looked at the records and nothing is there. The odd thing is that the behavior is only with some computers and not others when only using that affected Azure server as DNS. My local ones return regular entires.